# Up Button Customization in Action Bar

Tags: android, navigation, styles, android-actionbar

I want to add a standard Up Button icon ( < like this ) in action bar.

I added this in the styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/navigation_previous_item</item>
</style>
```

I enabled home Button in `onCreate`:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And added action event:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
       return true;
    }
```

**Problem is** that i can't see the ( < ) icon. Application icon is padded to the right, like there is a place for my drawable, but it doesn't show me the icon . . .

Comment: You also need to call: `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. See if using `getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation_previous_item))` after enabling the option helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thught i was calling that method :D

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept @andreich's answer since it proposes an identical approach.

Comment: setHomeAsUpIndicator was only added in api 18 unless your using the support library appcompat actionbar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try   `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`  and it should work